# Why is this meaning of "snipped" not in dictionaries?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, dictionaries

The word "snipped" can seemingly be used to mean "said in a snippy manner":

> "No," she snipped, obviously annoyed
>   —http://rosemarinetheater.blogspot.com/2013/05/white-boy-can-rap-looking-at-benny-in.html
>
> ...the former president was emphatic. "No," he snipped.
>   —http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/post-partisan/wp/2016/02/03/no-bernie-sanders-is-not-barack-obama
>
> "No," she snipped. "You're American, aren't you? You're not very popular here today."
> —http://www.city-journal.org/html/london-peace-marchers-say-long-live-intifada-9989.html

Yet no dictionary (of the dozen or so I consulted) documents this usage.  Not even the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/183280) [paywall], which documents every obscure meaning every word has had over the past 500 years.  Not even [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=-snip-), in which anyone can add words and definitions with no editorial oversight.

Is this meaning too rare for dictionaries to document?  It strikes me as a somewhat unusual but not obscure construction when I run across it.  But of course it's difficult to google for a word used with a specific meaning when that word also has a vastly more widely used meaning.  (You'll find a mix of hits and false positives searching for exact phrases such as "no she snipped," which is how I discovered the above citations.)

Is this meaning too new to have made it into any dictionaries?  The oldest of the above citations is from 2003, and again, my sense is that it's been around longer than that (though again, without a way to effectively search, it's hard to say).

Is this usage actually an erroneous substitution for another word?  "[Sniped](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=snipe)," for instance, can also be the verb in a dialogue tag, but it has a different meaning (one which could conceivably apply in the third citation above, but not the first two).  I can't think what other word might be intended.

Has this meaning been collectively overlooked by all the major dictionary compilers?  This seems extremely improbable, yet Sherlockianly correct.

Am I overlooking another possible explanation?

Comment: The latest generation of adults in the workplace happen to be very poorly educated - for the most part. I've run across too many with college degrees that can't put a sentence together. Short answer: They make stuff up that sounds right to them, and due to the advances in mass communication, it spreads. About 10 years ago, all the young corporate hot-shots got hooked on "verbage". One of my bosses said to me, "I refuse to continue this conversation until you adjust your verbage." I said, "Show me the word verbage in a dictionary, and I'll do it,"

Comment: "no she/he snipped" brings up about 40 results, and all of your examples are in there. A search for "he snipped at her" brings up 4 results from published fiction novels from 2007 onward. It's obviously used by some published writers, and used at least once by a Washington Post contributor. It seems it may not be popular enough either for lexicographers/editors to have noticed or for them to have considered it worthy of entry into their dictionary. Also, I don't think this is all too uncommon. Still, it is interesting.

Comment: @Oldbag The AHD and M-W dictionaries give alternative pronunciations of verbiage where the end of the word sounds the same as the ending to carriage or marriage. Maybe that's just how they roll.

Comment: The first example looks like the author meant to write "snapped".

Comment: @Zebrafish "I don't think this is all too uncommon": Is the _this_ in this sentence referring to the usage of _snipped_ under discussion, or is it referring to the practice of lexicographers considering certain usages not widespread enough to document?

Comment: Sorry. I meant it's not too uncommon for dictionaries to lack the specific definition we might see used, even when we have recorded instances of it (though few). People have suggested it's a mistake for or at least influenced by "snapped", or that it's interchangeable with "sniped". It's also possible it's being used metaphorically. Either way it hasn't reached the dictionaries, so I don't know what's happened with this meaning of "snipped".

Comment: @Oldbag It’s nothing to do with “the latest generation” – your exact argument has been used for millennia. People just don’t like language changing. I don’t remember who said it, but quite a good description of language change that fits the majority of people is that ‘correct and proper language’ is whatever you were taught as a child in primary school; anything which had already changed by that point is ‘archaic’; and anything that changes after that point is ‘lazy and uneducated’. (Also, _verbage_ is attested going back to the 18th century; it’s in the OED.)

Comment: @Zebrafish Thanks for clarifying. Part of the problem is that it's impossible for an amateur like me to tell how many recorded instances there are, because I can't search for just this usage. Lexicographers, this being their job, must have better tools at their disposal for that; they have thus far not considered this meaning worth documenting, which I find surprising, given the results I've been able to unearth just with my crude methodology. I'm more surprised that it's missing from Wiktionary, which tends to pick up newer words/meanings quicker than entrenched entities like Merriam Webster.

Comment: Now words are added to dictionaries all the time, for example: https://public.oed.com/updates/new-words-list-january-2018/ Just because someone wrote down a sequence of letters in a word, and someone else copied it, that doesn't make it a new word. It _may_ be a new word that eventually may be added to a dictionary. On the other hand, you will find things like "wierd" which, no matter how often it is used, is a misspelling of "weird" and not a new word.

Comment: You can't use the word in the 'meaning' : "said in a snippy manner". What meaning? Don't make me snip this question in the bud. [*snip*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/snip) : "to remove or cut off (something) by or as by cutting in this manner:" (it's a figurative use; can't have every use ever, listed)

Comment: @Mazura Few if any of the instances I found involve a speaker figuratively cutting off (i.e., interrupting) someone.  The common denominator of most usages seems to be speaking in a snippy manner.  And while _[snippy](http://www.m-w.com/dictionary/snippy)_ is derived from the verb _snip_, its meaning is different enough from its parent that when the parent verb is used as a shorthand to indicate the adjective, it should warrant listing a separate meaning (if this meaning is common enough), by the standards most dictionaries use for similar cases (see three examples in Sven Yargs's answer).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I guess you have a better dictionary than I, but, I'm not backing off on the abysmal stare of education these days. As for not liking changes in language, you couldn't be more wrong. I love new words, and I can't say I'm personally acquainted with anyone who has a problem with them. Progress requires new words. The issues arise when words are bastardized and pressed into service where a perfectly good, common word would suffice - but, does not happen to be a part of the user's vocabulary. It's just lazy.

Comment: @Oldbag Language change is not just about adding new words – in fact, that’s a minor part of it, and usually one that’s least objected to (if a new concept or thing is introduced, it needs a word to describe it; people have understood that always). Shifting meaning and pronunciation in existing words, grammatical rules changing, morphology changing – _those_ are the kinds of language change that pretty much everyone, throughout history, has deplored and worried about, along with the ‘decline’ in the state of education that is perceived as inextricably connected to them.

Comment: “Sherlockianly” 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As chasly from UK suggested in a now-deleted answer to this question, *snip* as a verb meaning "speak curtly or snappishly" probably originated as a back-formation from the adverb *snippily* or the adjective *snippy*, which *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) defines as follows:

> **snippy** *adj* **snippier. -est** (ca. 1848) **1 :** SHORT-TEMPERED, SNAPPISH **2 :** unduly brief or curt **3 :** putting on airs : SNIFFY — **snippily** *adv*

The phrase "said snippily" goes back to at least 1914 in Google Books and Hathi Trust search results. From Rose Macaulay, [*The Making of a Bigot*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt/search?q1=%22said%20snippily%22;id=uc1.31822038204798;view=1up;seq=1;start=1;sz=10;page=search;orient=0) (1914):

> > Mrs. Denison **said, snippily**, "Dorothy ought to know better," at the same moment that Eddy said, "It's a jolly little League, apparently. Quite full of truth."

From Shirley Seifert, "[The Nicest Boy and What the Smartest Girl in the Office Did to Him](https://books.google.com/books?id=U5xJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA79&dq=%22said+snippily%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH1qyW_53gAhUVIzQIHbqmBZEQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22said%20snippily%22&f=false)," in *The Delineator* (July-August 1920):

> "Isn't it a cold night?" she **said snippily** to the gloomy, immaculate young man who called for her at eight the night of the party.

Also, from a 1921 translation by Philip Allen of Johanna Spyri, [*Heidi*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=pst.000007496462;view=1up;seq=11):

> But it was hardly any time at all before Tinette thrust the tip of her nose in at the door and **said snippily**, just as always—"Off with you to the library!"
>
> ...
>
> Bring me this box full of nice fresh cakes like those we have with cofee, Tinette," said Clara, pointing to a little chest which had been standing there for just this purpose for a long time. The maid seized the object by one corner and let it dangle carelessly from her hand. After she had shut the door behind her, she **said snippily**—"Little things like that are no trouble at all."

Evidently, "snipped" has had more that a century to emerge as a short form of the phrase "said snippily."

Something similar seems to have happened with such verbs as *crabbed*, *grumped*, and *huffed*, which are likewise sometimes used as short-form alternatives to "said crabbily," "said grumpily," and "said huffily," respectively. But the *Eleventh Collegiate* accords each of these meanings a place in its dictionary:

> **crab** *vt* ... **2 :** to complain about peevishly ... *vi* **:** CARP, GROUSE {always *crabs* about the weather}
>
> ...
>
> **grump** *vi* ... **2 :** GRUMBLE, COMPLAIN ~ *vt* **:** to utter in a grumpy manner
>
> ...
>
> **huff** *vi* ... **2 a :** to make empty threats : BLUSTER ... *vt* ... **3 :** to utter with indignation or scorn

If *snip* in the sense of "say snippily" continues to appear in published works, it is only a matter of time before an additional entry for *snip* as a transitive verb, along the lines of "to utter curtly or snappishly," appears in some future Merriam-Webster's dictionary. In the long term, it's hard to say whether the word's prospects will be helped or hindered by its visual and aural similarity to *snap*, *sniff*, and *snipe*—all of which can be used as verbs in kindred senses.

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting question, in the sense that it touches upon the matter of this site:  what precisely allows some feature of language to count as ‘usage’.

You might start by asking a different question:  ‘criteria for adding a word to a dictionary’.  It’s not exactly your question, which is about new uses of old words, but it is a start.

Here is what Merriam Webster says:

> Criteria for adding a word to the dictionary
>   To be included in a Merriam-Webster dictionary, a word must be used in a substantial number of citations that come from a wide range of publications over a considerable period of time. ... The number and range of citations needed to add a word to the dictionary varies.

That used by Oxford Dictionaries is broadly consistent with that.  Of course, terms like ‘a substantial number’ and ‘wide range’ of publications and ‘considerable’ period of time.  Infuriating as the vagueness may seem, it is inevitable:  any boundary would be arbitrary and so possibly restrictive.

You should look carefully the idea of **range of publications** and **period of time**.  The issue is more than the number of uses.

Nevertheless, OED, Merriam Webster and most major dictionaries are keen not to fall behind the natural development of the English language.  So OED has a public site:

> public.oed.com

It gives you detailed guidance how to engage and propose words/uses not currently cited.

Answer (score 5):

It appears sniped and snipped are in many cases used interchangeably.  Your reference [American Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=snipe):

snipe (snīp)

> intr.v. **sniped**, snip·ing, snipes
>   1. To shoot at individuals from a concealed place.
>   2. To shoot snipe.
>   3. **To make malicious, underhand remarks or attacks.**

and the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/183282?redirectedFrom=sniped#eid) cites **sniped**

> fig. To assault with harsh sly criticism; to rebuke or censure
>   sharply; to make a carping attack at (someone).

As in:

> 1979   A. Hailey Overload i. xiv. 79   The press representatives had
>   eaten and imbibed with gusto, then in published reports, some **had
>   sniped** at GSP & L for extravagant entertaining at a time of rising
>   utility bills.

Comment: As a Brit, I'm not familiar with that meaning of ‘snipped’; it wouldn't surprise me to find it was mainly a US usage.

Comment: You cite definitions of the verb _snipe_ and a use of it consistent with those definitions.  Where is the evidence that _snipped_ is "in many cases used interchangeably" with it?  The meaning given for _snipe_ is not a good fit for many of the usages of _snipped_ my searches unearthed.  They do not seem interchangeable to me.